# Laggy TweenNano zoom and click effect

Tags: actionscript-3, optimization, zooming, lag, tween

I've implemented a click and zoom effect similar to this one: http://www.tutorialized.com/tutorial/Click-and-Zoom-Effect-in-Actionscript-3/76171

However, unlike in this example, the tween is extremely laggy. The rest of my program runs pretty good. This is the relevant code:

```
            var index:int = Main.collectedAirportArray.indexOf(this);

            var xPos:Number = Main.boardWidth * 0.5 - (this.x + this.width * 0.5) * SCALEFACTOR; 
            var yPos:Number = Main.boardHeight * 0.5 - (this.y + this.height * 0.5) * SCALEFACTOR;

            TweenNano.to(this.pMyParent.bg_image, 2, {x: xPos, y: yPos, scaleX: SCALEFACTOR, scaleY: SCALEFACTOR, ease:Sine.easeOut});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hard to tell, but I throw back some questions that hopefully will help you.

## 1 - How big is this image?

## 2 - How often are you calling this method? (is it inside a loop or something?)

If you have a big image, one thing you can do is change the stage quality to *medium*, when you finish the  tween, then you can change it back to *best*.

Cheers,